# Suggestions for best design pattern for unittesting Excel readin in Pandas

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.x

When I read about unittests I keep reading that I shouldn't rely on external resources, but in some cases I would like to test reading in Excel files so I can be confident this portion of my code is working.

For instance if I'm using pandas I might want to unittest that Excel files are being read with no errors.

```
import pandas as pd
import pytest

def test_excel_fileread():
    assert pd.read_excel("SomeTestFile.xlsx")
```

Is this a good idea? And if so how what's a good way to structure my test directory and code to accommodate for this as test runners like pytest?

Comment: Just because unittests should not rely on external resources does not mean you cannot have *other kind of automated tests* which do. Just call them not unittests.

Comment: I consider the entire idea of "unit tests shouldn't access files" doubtful. If the job of your code is to deal with complex structures typically found in files, you *have* to have example structures, and the obvious move is to bundle example files with the test. Why, philosophically, should it be wrong to store your unit test data in a file, but right to awkwardly stuff the structure inline into the test class instead? After all, the test class is more than likely also in a file on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you want to test?

"No errors" means run time operational code.  Those are exceptions.

If you want to test your file reading behavior you either need some set files to test against or decouple that behavior from files.  File streams aren't the only streams.

It's ok to move logic away from peripherals so it can be tested.  This leaves simple connectivity logic behind that isn't nearly as important to test.

Comment: I want to test stuff that happens during the file readin. For example I want to ensure that dates are being read in a certain format because I am running into errors when they're not.

Comment: Getting errors when getting bad data is a good thing.  Better than creating bad records.  All unit tests can do here is make sure the errors you want raised will be raised in the cases you imagine.

Comment: "make sure the errors you want raised will be raised in the cases you imagine" this is what I would like to test for